# review page using nodejs and mongodb

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

I am new to Nodejs and mongoDB. I want to create two pages:account updating of a user (if a user wants to update his/her profile picture,email,name,... save them into database) and review page to review a product or a person(tutor).
I would need links or if anyone can provide a code for me.

Comment: SO is NOT:  "Do my homework!" site.

Comment: It is not even a homework! I am willing to learn...

Answer (score 0):

Well you specified you need link here the one which would help you

http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/

Comment: Thank you, but I need  something related to user's profile and review pages and I must use html